# devlink not available on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server

I am trying to run this command:

```
devlink dev eswitch set pci/0000:88:00.0 mode switchdev
```

However this is what I am getting:

```
devlink: command not found
```

Any idea how to install devlink?

NOTE:

I already tried installing iproute2

```
root@zeus-54:~# sudo apt install iproute2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
iproute2 is already the newest version (4.3.0-1ubuntu3.16.04.4).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 202 not to upgrade.
root@zeus-54:~# devlink
devlink: command not found
root@zeus-54:~#
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

apparently devlink is not in ubuntu 16.04 but it is in 18.04.
I got it working after upgrade the system to 18.04.